# After 10.7.3 update network does not work in a Vmware virtual machine

Tags: windows-xp, osx-lion, updates, vmware-fusion

I have a macbook running OS X 10.7.2. I run windows xp as virtual machine using vmware fusion 4.0.2. Recently I updated OS X to 10.7.3 and network does not work anymore on the windows xp virtual machine, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is the network adapter missing in the VM? Does it have an IP? What are your network settings in Fusion?

Comment: This seems to be a widespread issue.

Comment: @flow Can you post your vmnet adapter settings — from OS X terminal, type 'ifconfig' and post the vmnet entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying your VM's .vmx config:

How-to from [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014782):

1. Ensure the virtual machine is shut down (not suspended).
2. In Fusion, from the Apple menu bar, go to Window > Virtual Machine Library.
3. Hold the Option (Alt) key and right-click the virtual machine. Select Open Config File in Editor.
4. If the these lines are missing, add them:

   ```
   ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
   ethernet0.connectionType = "bridged"
   ethernet0.virtualDev = "vmxnet3"
   ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
   ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
   ethernet0.linkStatePropagation.enable = "TRUE"
   ```
5. When finished, click Save a version (Lion) or Save (not Save As) (Snow Leopard and earlier), and exit.

The changes made to the .vmx do not take effect until the next time Fusion is opened (quit it first, if it is currently open). Alternatively, double-click the .vmx file to apply the changes and open the virtual machine immediately.

Comment: thanks a lot. I did it but the problem now is that the ethernet card is not recognized after reboot, windows says it needs to install drivers but can not find them, any hints?

Comment: Try replacing `e1000` with `vmxnet3`. Make sure you have vmware tools installed.

Comment: Also, specifically, what version of XP are you running? Professional or Home? 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: changing to vmxnet3 and now it works, thanks a lot !!!